# Помогите разбить многомерный массив PHP

Tags: php

Прошу помощи, не могу додуматься!

Есть у меня таблица в БД.

Вот такая структура. У каждой записи, есть поле `param`, там число от 1 до 4, на основании этого числа мне нужно все записи рассортировать по 4 . Всего 26 элементов в таблице:

```
[
0 => app\models\Paramdoor#1
(
    [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => [
        'id' => 1
        'name' => 'Стандарт'
        'price' => ''
        'param' => 1
        'content' => 'Коробочный брус'
        'disabled' => 1
    ]
)
1 => app\models\Paramdoor#2
(
    [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => [
        'id' => 2
        'name' => '1 комплект'
        'price' => '601 грн'
        'param' => 1
        'content' => 'Коробочный брус Стандарт'
        'disabled' => 0
    ]       
)
```

Создаю 4 пустых массива:

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();
$arr3 = array();
$arr4 = array();
```

Как я понимаю через `foreach` я пробегаю многомерный массив:

```
foreach ($params as $param=>$row) {
 if($row[param]==1){
  $arr1[]=$row;
}
else if($row[param]==2){
 $arr2[]=$row;
}
else if($row[param]==3){
 $arr3[]=$row;
}
else if($row[param]==4){
 $arr4[]=$row;
}
}
```

И так получаю 4 разных массива под каждый `<select>`.

Интересует вот что - есть ли более элегантный способ?

Comment: а что мешает сделать один хэш массивов ?

`$paramArr[$row[$param]][]=$row`

Comment: на правах слоупока: такая конструкция - это типичный switch, if else if здесь не нужен.

Comment: И Я бы советовал забыть про конструкцию ifelse в php, для это есть switch!

Comment: Ну совсем забывать не надо ))) Для случаев как здесь: x==1, x==2 и т.д. действительно switch больше подходит.

Comment: @eicto но если очень хочется отдельные массивы, `${"arr" . $row["param"]}[] = $row;`

Answer (score 2):

Кажется вот это вам подойдет:

```
list($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4) = $params;
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach($params as $item) {
   $arrName = "arr".intval($item['param']);
   ${$arrName}[] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Или так)

```
   foreach($params as $item)
    {
       $arr[$item['param']][] = $item;
    }
```